# Azure App Registration: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

**Verified Publisher:** I have an application in Azure AD, and under `Brandings and properties` the Publisher is verified (I had to host a file `.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json`).

[image]

---

**Verified Domains:** I have also added the `Custom domains`, and they too are `verified`, for both the domain and the subdomain.

[image]

---

**Goal:**

The bigger goal here is to use the Microsoft Graph API.
This is not a new Application Registration, but an update to an existing registration. The application has also been published in the Microsoft Store prior to the updates; Which might have registered the application "magically" in Azure AD under the `Applications from personal account`.

---

**Problem:**

I now want to alter this application, to be able to make use the Graph API calls. And from what I understand I first need to configure the application, for Signing In, and also enable it to be Multi-tenant.

When I then modify the `manifest` file, to be use `AzureADMultipleOrgs`, I am presented with an error that has indicated I need unique `identifierUris`.

Yet when I change the value of

> "identifierUris": [],

to

> "identifierUris": ["https://product.mydomain.name"], (*without the training slash*)

I get the following Error:

`Error detail: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain`

### [image]

**This error appears to be misleading? What is actually wrong here?**

Comment: App Store questions are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing indicates that the value of the identifierUris property should be a verified domain or its subdomain.

If you recently added and verified the domain and this app was recently converted from a Single tenant App to Multi-tenant App then general recommendation would be to try registering a new application registration and then publishing the identifierURI's. As at times conversion of app from Single tenant to Multi-tenant can fail resulting in such issues.